# Not able to install App in new Kindle Fire HD emulator

Tags: android, kindle-fire

Did anyone face any problems installing the App on the new Kindle Fire HD? I followed all the steps given by Amazon but it does not installs the App. I tried from both Eclipse and ADB.

Comment: what message do you get?

Comment: I did not get any message. When I run through eclipse, it launches the Emulator but doesnt runs my app. When I try to do an adb install, the control in cmd comes to next line but nuthing else happens.

Comment: My question is if anyone was able to install their app on the emulator till now.

Comment: I got it. When I launched the emulator from ADB and subsequently did an ad install, it worked, although it took some time to install it. I think the problem was that I was launching the emulator through eclipse and doing an ADB install. Not sure why isnt it working with Eclipse though.

Comment: Is the emulator an virtual machine in Virtual box(like the playbook emulator)?

Comment: I dont think so. Not sure about running it in virtual box, but i am not doing anything fancy. Simply changing the build path and running as an Android app from eclipse, but it doesnt works.